# pack equilateral triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I'm working on a problem of inscribing equilateral triangle for some time now and it goes like this :

> using only a foot rule and a compasses , show a way of inscribing an equilateral triangle into an arbitrary triangle.

I looked throughout the internet and didn't find any clues about the path to the solution of this problem. the direction I am thinking about is :
the problem can be solved easily for inscribing an equilateral triangle into another equilateral triangle by choosing the middle of each side of the outer triangle to be the vertices of the inscribed triangle , I am trying to found the general rule for the case where the outer triangle is an arbitrary one based on the observation of the described above equilateral triangle. I can't seem to get the right general rule. after I will find a general way to do it I will think about how to accomplish it by using only a foot rule and a compasses.

I think that it can be useful for a range of such problems to get the right direction to the solution of this problem.

Thanks ,

Comment: "packing" just means "inscribing"?  Or are you actually looking for a configuration of equilateral triangles which cover the given one? (not sure what that might mean for a general triangle....)

Comment: What do you mean by pack a triangle to another one

Comment: I mean that I want to pack/inscribe only one equilateral triangle into an arbitrary triangle so that the packed triangle vertices will lie on the sides of the arbitrary triangle.

Comment: So, just "inscribe" then. "packing" means something very different (a configuration of congruent or similar figures).

Comment: Ok , I will edit , thanks.

Comment: Hint:  pick an acute angle of your triangle and inscribe a small equilateral triangle with one vertex on each of the two sides which comprise the angle (the third vertex should hang freely in the triangles interior).  Draw a line connecting the original triangle vertex to the freely hanging vertex and extend that to the third side of the original triangle.

Comment: Lulu , thanks a lot!